# jtable and intellij - how do i set the columns to appear next to the the right side

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jxtable

On intellij I have created a JXTable on a JPanel.
I have added two columns and set their width.
I want the panel too be much longer then the jxtable and so i set its size to be very large.
The problem is that the columns are are added to the left side.
Is there a way to make them added to the right side of the table area?
I have tried

```
  jxtable.setAlignment(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT)
```

but with no success

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an appropriate layout manager.  Check out this link: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

From your description a `FlowLayout` set to `RIGHT` sounds like the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question, but here is one way you can place a table in a panel that is larger than the table:

```
final JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
// initialize your panel with stuff

final JXTable smallTable = new JXTable(...);
bigPanel.add( smallTable, BorderLayout.LINE_START ); // Left side of panel
bigPanel.add( smallTable, BorderLayout.LINE_END );   // Right side of panel
bigPanel.add( smallTable, BorderLayout.PAGE_START ); // Top of panel
bigPanel.add( smallTable, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);    // Bottom of panel
bigPanel.add( smallTable, BorderLayout.CENTER );     // Center of panel
```